# ScrollView is getting extended

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I have a ScrollView which should allow to scroll its content when necessary, e.g. when switched from Portrait orientation to Landscape orientation.

When I start in Portrait orientation it looks like in the following screenshot and is exactly what I want. The green area is restricted to the upper part up to the Bottom-Tabs:

[image]

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Grid IgnoreSafeArea="True">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="*, 55">

        <!-- Sharpnado View Switcher to switch between different Views -->
        <tabs:ViewSwitcher x:Name="Switcher"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Animate="True"
                           SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedViewModelIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">

            <tabs:DelayedView x:TypeArguments="views:CalculateView"
                              BindingContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CalculateViewModel}}"
                              AccentColor="{StaticResource Gray100}"
                              Animate="True"                              
                              UseActivityIndicator="True" />

            <tabs:DelayedView x:TypeArguments="views:OverviewView"
                              BindingContext="{Binding Source={viewModels:OverviewViewModel}}"
                              AccentColor="{StaticResource Gray100}"
                              Animate="True"
                              UseActivityIndicator="True" />

        </tabs:ViewSwitcher>
            

        <!-- Tabs at the Bottom -->
        <tabs:TabHostView x:Name="TabHost"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          BackgroundColor="White"
                          Orientation="Horizontal"
                          TabType="Fixed"
                          SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={x:Reference Switcher}, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">

            <tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>
                <tabs:BottomTabItem Style="{StaticResource BottomTab}"
                                    IconImageSource="house_solid.png"
                                    Label="View 1"
                                    Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>

                <tabs:BottomTabItem Style="{StaticResource BottomTab}"
                                    IconImageSource="apple_solid.png"
                                    Label="View 2" />

            </tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>
        </tabs:TabHostView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**CalculateView.xaml**

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *">

    <!--Just a Background Image and a LinearGradient-->
    <views:BackgroundImageView x:Name="BackgroundImage" VerticalOptions="Start"/>

    <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Background="Green">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Label 1"/>
            <Label Text="Label 2"/>
            <Label Text="Label 3"/>
            <Label Text="Label 4"/>
            <Label Text="Label 5"/>
            <Label Text="Label 6"/>
            <Label Text="Label 7"/>
            <Label Text="Label 8"/>
            <Label Text="Label 9"/>
            <Label Text="Label 10"/>
            <Label Text="Label 11"/>
            <Label Text="Label 12"/>
            <Label Text="Label 13"/>
            <Label Text="Label 14"/>
            <Label Text="Label 15"/>
            <Label Text="Label 16"/>
            <Label Text="Label 17"/>
            <Label Text="Label 18"/>
            <Label Text="Label 19"/>
            <Label Text="Label 20"/>
            <Label Text="Label 21"/>
            <Label Text="Label 22"/>
            <Label Text="Label 23"/>
            <Label Text="Label 24"/>
            <Label Text="Label 25"/>
            <Label Text="Label END"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</Grid>
```

When I switch to **Landscape orientation** it does not come out as I expected no matter I did with the the VerticalOptions of the ScrollView (currently also set to FillAndExpand):

[image]

In Portrait orientation the green area is restricted and only filled up to the Bottom-Tab. Same I want for the Landscape Orientation. Right now, it also is green behind/below the Bottom-Tab part.

Another problem is that the content of the ScrollView can't be scrolled which tells me that the ScrollView itself seems to be too high.

But why is it calculated correctly in Portrait orientation and not in Landscape? How could I restrict the ScrollView to the area up to the Bottom-Tab and then allow the content to be scrolled?

Comment: 1) If you start the device in Landscape, is it correct? Looks like ScrollView height isn't recalculated when rotate. There were bugs with this, but they were fixed in 2022. Perhaps no one tried ScrollView inside Auto-sized Grid Row. 2) As a test, have CalculateView ONLY contain the ScrollView: Remove its outer Grid and the background image. Does that rotate correctly? 3) Bottom line: its probably a Maui bug. Simplify the code as much as possible while causing the bug. Make a new issue at `github maui issues`, with link to a public repo containing runnable project.

Comment: 1) I also started the App in Landscape and it was the same result. Interestingly, when I rotate it also behaves correctly and the it is recalculated correctly for Portrait orientation. Switching back to Landscape is as in my original question (wrong behavior as expected). I also tried with VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" and HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" (maybe they switched Vertical and Horizontal when in Landscape mode), but same behavior.

Comment: You mentioned *"Perhaps no one tried ScrollView inside Auto-sized Grid Row"*: well, I changed the outer Grid within "CalculateView.xaml" from ```RowDefinitions="Auto"``` to ```RowDefinitions="*"``` and here we go - it seems to work now. Would you say it might still be a Bug or is the problem on my side? I'd still expect to have it working with ```RowDefinitions="Auto"``` to be honest

Comment: By the way, I can show several other examples, where Heights are not (re-)calculated correctly on different platforms also different behavior. Latest example is a BottomSheet element for which I calculated the HeightRequest based on the height which comes with OnSizeAllocated(...) on the parent. When started in Portrait orientation the size is 75% of the available height, which I. Turned to Landscape and Height gets 100% of the available height, turned again to other Landscape option and Height gets 75%, turned again to Portrait and size stays at the HeightRequest of Landscape orientation

Comment: Also inside such an Element also inner sizes are not always (re-)calculated on Android for example. Sometimes a problem occurs on Android, sometimes on iOS. I test everything on both platforms just to make sure everything looks the same and very often one or the other does have a problem - really annoying and frustrating for me. Can't write a Bug with a reproducible example all the time as it is very time-consuming stripping out from a running App

Comment: Yes, it still sounds like a bug. (As do the other calculation glitches you mention.) Up to you whether it is worth your time making a test case for the devs. Sounds like you managed to work around it.

Comment: Yes, seems like a workaround an I am considering writing a Bug. First of all, I think I should write something for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77033311/scrollview-with-underlying-elements-update-of-bindings-not-working since to me, it seems like a severe one and hope it still can be fixe for .NET 8 release?

Comment: Is that other question's bug covered by https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17211? If not, yes please write it up.

Comment: That’s not covered by the issue above, I think. The above issue is about the DataBinding and here it is about Layouting. Writing the issue will certainly take some time to get a minimal reproducible example (that's always the biggest concern for me getting it out of the entire app)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - I created a new issue for that if you want to have a look https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17291

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - In this issue they mentioned, that I used an older version and this is an issue with that. I don’t know, but .NET 8 has not been released, so far, right? So, the version I used is the current one. Would you use a preview version of VS and also .NET 8 preview in my case? I just remember the problems caused by VS 17.7.3 update and my app not working anymore, more possibilities to connect to my Mac. Would you change to such a preview version or do you have experiences with that version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for the hint from @ToolmakerSteve in comment above regarding "Auto-sized Grid Row":

What seems to work now, was changing the outer Grid of **CalculateView.xaml** to a Grid with RowDefinitions="*":

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="*">

    <!--Just the Background Image and the LinearGradient-->
    <views:BackgroundImageView x:Name="BackgroundImage" VerticalOptions="Start"/>

    <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ScrollView" Background="Green">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Label 1"/>
            <Label Text="Label 2"/>
            <Label Text="Label 3"/>
            <Label Text="Label 4"/>
            <Label Text="Label 5"/>
            <Label Text="Label 6"/>
            <Label Text="Label 7"/>
            <Label Text="Label 8"/>
            <Label Text="Label 9"/>
            <Label Text="Label 10"/>
            <Label Text="Label 11"/>
            <Label Text="Label 12"/>
            <Label Text="Label 13"/>
            <Label Text="Label 14"/>
            <Label Text="Label 15"/>
            <Label Text="Label 16"/>
            <Label Text="Label 17"/>
            <Label Text="Label 18"/>
            <Label Text="Label 19"/>
            <Label Text="Label 20"/>
            <Label Text="Label 21"/>
            <Label Text="Label 22"/>
            <Label Text="Label 23"/>
            <Label Text="Label 24"/>
            <Label Text="Label 25"/>
            <Label Text="Label END"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</Grid>
```

This, I also tried with and without VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" and HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" and both options seemed to work.