# ScrollView with underlying elements update of Bindings not working

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App I use a nested structure of Elements in a ScrollView.

When using a ScrollView, my Bindable parts do not get updated anymore.

```xml
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="BorderStyleView" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource White}" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeShape" Value="RoundRectangle 10, 10, 10, 10" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="BorderHeadline" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}" />
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="VerticalItemTemplate" x:DataType="{x:Type databaseModels:Selection}">
            <sho:DraggableViewCell>
                <ContentView>
                    <SwipeView>
                        
                        <Border Padding="15, 0, 15, 0" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
                            <Grid RowDefinitions="*, 20" ColumnDefinitions="120, Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto, 70, Auto">

                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FoodItem.Name}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>

                                <Entry Placeholder="Abc" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="g" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0, 0, 5, 0"/>

                            </Grid>

                            </Grid>
                        </Border>


                        <SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <SwipeItems>
                                <SwipeItem Text="{loc:Translate CalculateText}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}" 
                                           Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:CalculateViewModel}}, Path=ExcludeItemCommand}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.RightItems>
                    </SwipeView>

                </ContentView>
            </sho:DraggableViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>

        <toolkit:IntToBoolConverter x:Key="IntToBoolConverter" />
    
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>

<Grid RowDefinitions="*">

    <!--Just the Background Image and the LinearGradient-->
    <views:BackgroundImageView x:Name="BackgroundImage" VerticalOptions="Start"/>

    <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto">

            <Border Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleView}" Opacity="0.85" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="15, 0, 15, -10" MinimumHeightRequest="300" >

                <StackLayout Background="Red">

                    <!-- Heading -->
                    <Label Text="{loc:Translate MealHeaderText, StringFormat='{0}:'}" Style="{StaticResource BorderHeadline}"  Padding="15, 15, 15, 5" />

                    <!-- Min, Amount-->
                    <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="0, 10, 0, -5" IsVisible="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, Converter={StaticResource IntToBoolConverter}}">
                        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="150, 0, 10, 0" >
                            <Label Text="Min"/>
                            <Label Text="{loc:Translate AmountColumnString}"/>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>


                    <!-- CollectionView to display the Selected Items -->
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="*" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" HeightRequest="500">
                        
                        <sho:CollectionView CollectionPadding="10, 10, 10, 10"
                                            EnableDragAndDrop="True"
                                            DragAndDropDirection="VerticalOnly"
                                            DragAndDropTrigger="LongTap"
                                            ItemHeight="80"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=OneWay}"
                                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VerticalItemTemplate}"
                                            MinimumHeightRequest="250"
                                            AnimateScroll="True"
                                            DisableScroll="False"
                                            CollectionLayout="Vertical"/>
                    </Grid>

                </StackLayout>
            </Border>

        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>

</Grid>
```

**ViewModel-Code**:

```cs
public ObservableRangeCollection<SelectionItem> SelectedFoodItems { get; set; }

public CalculateViewModel()
{    
    SelectedItems = new ObservableRangeCollection<SelectionItem>();
}

private async Task FilterSelectedItems()
{
    var selectedItems = GroupedSelectionItems.SelectMany(groupedSelectionItem => groupedSelectionItem).Where(selectionItem => selectionItem.IsSelected == true).ToList();

    SelectedItems.Clear();
    SelectedItems.AddRange(selectedItems);

    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItems));

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Before the OnPropertyChanged(...), I can definitively see that there are Items inside SelectedItems and SelectedItems.Count is > 0.

My Binding on HorizontalStackLayout property "IsVisible" does not work anymore and does not provide any value to the HorizontalStackLayout. I also tried and provided a boolean value instead of SelectedItems.Count to get rid of the IntToBoolConverter, but also without any effect. Is visible with a Binding-Property is ignored here.

What is also not working correctly is the Update of Items in the CollectionView. They just get visible, when I scroll my CollectionView. This does not have any impact on the IsVisible-Property above what I kind of expected in this case.

When I remove the ScrollView my Binding to IsVisible is working again and also the Elements I add to the CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=OneWay}" works again without scrolling.

What I wanted to achieve is that the HorizontalStackLayout is only visible when there are selected Items and also when an Item is selected and is in the `ObservableRangeCollection<SelectionItem> SelectedItems { get; set; }` collection they get visible in the CollectionView.

Is there a reason for that behavior in my Code or anything I can do to have a way around this?

I definitively want to scroll the elements and therefore used the ScrollView, but it seems like that everything which is Bound below my ScrollView is not working regarding Binding anymore.

If this is really the case this is a severe Bug to me and meens like you can't use the ScrollView having Layouts with Bindings underneath.

Do you guys see any way around?

Comment: 1. May I know on which platform the issue particular exists? 2. What is `sho:` in your xaml, could you please help create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add it to your post?

Comment: I am working with VS 17.7.2 as the last update 17.7.3 screwed everything up and had to be rolled back. So it’s the latest with this version. I am working with Pixel 5 Emulator API 33 Version. 2) sho is Sharpnado which I use. 3) I try to create this minimal example, but as you understand not so easy from a working App to create such a minimal example

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT - interestingly, when I move the ScrollView around the ```<Grid RowDefinitions="*">``` like ```<ScrollView><Grid RowDefinitions="*"> ... </Grid></ScrollView>```it is working. Downside here: it also moves my BackgroundImageView

Comment: Does anybody have an idea that provides a better Workaround or anything I can do?

Comment: thanks for your response! If you remove the `ScrollView` and the Binding is working again, consider it's a bug, you can report a [new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) on Github.

Comment: Yes, it is like that, but I am not able to create a minimal example that exactly shows that. When I strip down the example or create the situation as a new example it seems to work. I am pretty sure it is a bug, but like this it difficult to show it

Comment: Thanks for the response! I can understand what you mean(it's hard to create a minimal example).

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT - are you also in the MAUI development Team? Maybe another approach could be to check the Code regarding Updates of DataBindings when ScrollViews are used with deeper nested elements vs. ScrollView wrapped around these elements? Does the Code show any hints that DataBinding is just provided to a certain nesting level or any other clues where it might get lost.

Comment: 1. I would suggest you can directly report [a new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) on Github because they are Product Team. 2. What if you replace the ScrollView with VerticalStackLayout, will the DataBindings fail?

Comment: Replacing the ScrollView by a StackLayout or a VerticalStackLayout directly works. I tried it in different nesting levels and it seemed to work. Well, can't scroll that way, otherwise I would have used it as my workaround. So, my current workaround is to set the ScrollView around my Grid as described above. Yes, I can write a new issue, but my experience is not good without a minimal reproducible example. All of such issues were closed. When I compare it with what we do at work with our issues this process is just ignoring them to be honest. We still try to reproduce scenarios or analyze them

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17211

Comment: Thanks for your response, I posted an answer and concluded what we achieved so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the DataBinding of the `IsVisible` property function well, you may need to remove the [ScrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview) around the [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid) and then wrap the [ScrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview) with the outer [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid), the only disadvantage of the workaround is that it'll also scroll the BackgroundImageView.

```
<ScrollView>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="*">

        <views:BackgroundImageView/>

        <!--<ScrollView Grid.Row="0"> -->

            <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto">

                <!--Omitted for brevity>

            </Grid>
        <!--</ScrollView>-->

    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

Also, there's a known issue that being tracked in the link below, you can follow up there.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17211